# find region in image emgucv

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kumh3.png)

[after image](http://image.fileslink.com/432e5fd3daea306/%EC%BA%A1%EC%B2%98.PNG)

how to find rectangle region in image?

It can be not exactly.

i tried to use "CvInvoke.findContours" but i failed because don't know how to use.

please tell me what should i do

i need function that return region rectangles, or some hints please..

sorry and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to create an image where the regions that you want are highlighted and the regions you don't want are black. To do this, I would do an adaptive threshold (you'll want to convert the image to black and white and then use the invert threshold option to highlight the non-white areas).

Then I would use morphology (dilation followed by erosion, or 'closing') to remove the noise. The image should now have white blobs on the regions you're interesting in and be black elsewhere. The final steps will be find contours, follows by looping over each contour and finding their bounding boxes.

You'll want to read up on each of these topics, but that approach should work for what you want. Opencv's documentation isn't great, and EmGU's bindings adds another layer of confusion, but be patient and you'll get the hang of it.

Adaptive threshold:
https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html

Morphology: https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/opening_closing_hats/opening_closing_hats.html

find contours:
https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours

bounding rect:
https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=boundingrect#boundingrect

Answer (score 0):

here is the link that contains
[shape detection](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Shape_(Triangle,_Rectangle,_Circle,_Line)_Detection_in_CSharp#Emgu_CV_3.x) using emgu.